# Python turning multiple objects into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I've got an Object which has a name and an indefinite amount of parameters (which is also an object with a name and a value)

I'm pretty new to python so this gets a bit over my head
I want to get all parameters and put them into a dictionary. My code looks like this:

```
data = {}

for parameter in object.parameters:
    parameter.__dict__
    data.update({parameter})
```

But parameter.__dict__ doesn't work like I thought here.
Any ideas how i can make it work?

EDIT: Thanks it worked by using data.update(vars(parameter))

Comment: `parameter.__dict__` returns the object attributes dictionary. You don't do anything with that, you are ignoring the expression result. Did you mean to use it in `data.update(parameter.__dict__)`? Note that it is more readable and clearer to use the `vars()` function: `data.update(vars(parameter))`.

Comment: Did you mean `data.update(parameter.__dict__)`?

Comment: Changed it to varse and now it works, but I'd like to get a dictionary like {"ParamOne": "ValueOne", "ParamTwo": "ValueTwo"}
At the moment I get
{'name': 'ParamOne', 'value': 'ValueOne'}
{'name': 'ParamTwo', 'value': 'ValueTwo'}
I don't want every parameter to be called like these so I can't just go ParamOne = "ValueOne"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your output it looks like you class structure is something like this

```
class class1(object):
    def __init__(self, p1, p2):
        self.name =  p1
        self.value = p2

class class2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.parameters = [class1("param1", "value1"), class1("param2", "value2")]


obj = class2()

data = {}
```

So when we do

```
for parameter in obj.parameters:
    print(parameter.__dict__)
```

We get output

```
{'value': 'value1', 'name': 'param1'}
{'value': 'value2', 'name': 'param2'}
```

So to get the desired output you will have to do something like

```
for parameter in obj.parameters:
    data[parameter.__dict__['name']] = parameter.__dict__['value']

print(data)
```

Which will give your desired output

```
{'param2': 'value2', 'param1': 'value1'}
```